# Pyqt5 how to set URL and show the page

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengine

I am studing python and making bookmark function for practice purpose.
Now I could register url to tab menu.
and when I press the link from tab menu. nothing shows on browser.
following area, somebody please le me know what is wrong.
"self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(action_url))"
text itself(action_url) looks OK, but browser does not show.

entire code is this.

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QAction,
    QApplication,
    QDialog,
    QDialogButtonBox,
    QFileDialog,
    QLabel,
    QLineEdit,
    QMainWindow,
    QToolBar,
    QVBoxLayout,
)



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://google.com"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        
        # tag::navigation1[]
        navtb = QToolBar("Navigation")
        navtb.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))
        self.addToolBar(navtb)
        
        #bookmark button
        bookmark_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join("icons", "smiley.png")), "Bookmark", self)
        bookmark_btn.setStatusTip("add to bookmark")
        bookmark_btn.triggered.connect(self.add_bookmark)
        navtb.addAction(bookmark_btn)        
        navtb.addSeparator()

        # tag::menuBookmark[]   
        self.bookmark_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Bookmark")        
        bookmark_select_action = QAction("http://google.com",self)
        bookmark_select_action.triggered.connect(self.navigate_bookmark)
        self.bookmark_menu.addAction(bookmark_select_action)
            
        self.show()

    
    # tag::bookmark[]    
    def add_bookmark(self):
        bookmark_title = self.browser.page().title()
        bookmark_url = self.browser.url().toString()
        bookmark_select_action = QAction(bookmark_url,self)
        bookmark_select_action.triggered.connect(self.navigate_bookmark)
        
        self.bookmark_menu.addAction(bookmark_select_action)
            
    
    # tag::navigationBookmark[]   
    def navigate_bookmark(self):
        action = self.sender()
        action_url = '"'+action.text()+'"'
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(action_url))   #this code does not function as I expected
        print(action_url)
        


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setApplicationName("Mozzarella Ashbadger")
app.setOrganizationName("Mozzarella")
app.setOrganizationDomain("mozzarella.org")

window = MainWindow()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you put the text inside the quotation marks. In general if you have a string and you want to convert it to `QUrl` use `QUrl::fromUserInput()`, also use the `load()` method:

```py
def navigate_bookmark(self):
    action = self.sender()
    url = QUrl.fromUserInput(action.text())
    self.browser.load(url)
```

Another strategy is to save the QUrl in the QAction and then retrieve it:

```py
def add_bookmark(self):
    bookmark_title = self.browser.page().title()
    bookmark_url = self.browser.url()
    bookmark_select_action = QAction(bookmark_url.toString(), self)
    bookmark_select_action.setData(bookmark_url)
    # or
    # bookmark_select_action.setProperty("url", bookmark_url)
    bookmark_select_action.triggered.connect(self.navigate_bookmark)
    self.bookmark_menu.addAction(bookmark_select_action)
```

```py
def navigate_bookmark(self):
    action = self.sender()
    url = action.data()
    # or
    # url = action.property("url")
    self.browser.load(url)
```

Comment: Thank you  for the comment. 
I tried 2nd one. (following)
" url = QUrl.fromUserInput(action.text()) "

That worked as exected!!

Comment: @Taniguchi Please read [ask] and review the [tour]